# Is it possible to dual boot chrome os and ubuntu on a samsung chromebook 5?

Tags: dual-boot

I found some info about this when googling but it is pretty confusing. I thought I would ask the pros. If this can be done, I would like some direction as far as where to go for correct information and downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  Here is a detailed install guide. You will have a dual boot system with Ubuntu and ChromeOS on two separate SSD drives when completed.

http://techfoobar.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-samsungs-new.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.